# How to use Qiskit visualization in Python IDLE 3.X (Python 3.X 64-bit)?

Tags: qiskit

Why doesn't Qiskit visualization work on Python IDLE 3.X like `circuits.draw()`, `plot_histogram()` and `plot_bloch_vector()`? Is there any way to make visualization module work on Python IDLE 3.X?

Comment: Hello! What do you mean by it doesn't work, does it throw up an error?

Comment: No,It doesn't show any error but even it doesn't plot anything.Although it's prints results and counts properly @met927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions don't automatically display their output, unless you are running the code in a Jupyter notebook. I would recommend you switch over to using a Jupyter notebook if you can (you can do this inside the [IBM Q Experience](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/)) as this will display all the plots for you, as long as the calls to these functions are the last line of the cell.

If this is not possible, you can display the circuit using ASCII art by calling `print(circuit.draw())` or saving it to a file using `circuit.draw(output='mpl', filename='circuit.png')`. As for the other plotting methods, these return matplotlib images so you should be able to see them by doing `plt.show()` or save the figure by doing

```
bloch = plot_bloch_vector()
bloch.savefig('bloch.png')
```